# Keeping API data fresh with Android and Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android app that pulls information from an API and displays it in a Recyclerview. Everything works however, I just have 1 `GET request` when the app is opened (using Volley).

I'd like to have the information in the recycler view update every 5 seconds. I'm new to Java and couldn't find any other questions or resources online that explain how to most efficiently keep information from an active API up to date. Should I `Get Request` every 5 seconds, if so how do you best implement this? If not, is there a more proper way.

Any feedback would help me and I'm sure a bunch of future developers. My current code below for refrence.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String URL_DATA = "https://summerproject17.herokuapp.com/api/request/";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                        o.getString("room"),
                                        o.getString("request"),
                                        o.getString("time")
                                );
                                listItems.add(item);
                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.Java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `Handler` to call the url after every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        try {

                            // update data 
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 5000 ms or 5 secs
    }
```